# How to automatically save extracted data on Sharepoint

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pycharm

Can someone help me on how to add directory path code to Sharepoint wherein the extracted data will automatically save on Sharepoint instead on local file. I am using Python script, PyCharm, and Selenium. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import openpyxl
import csv
import codecs
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # Add this import statement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")  # Maximize the browser window
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")  # Disable infobars
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")  # Disable browser extensions
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Disable /dev/shm usage
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Disable sandbox mode
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])  # Exclude the enable-automation switch
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)  # Disable the automation extension



# Update the path to the ChromeDriver executable
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


try:
current_datetime = datetime.now()
current_date = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
current_time = current_datetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
current_dt = current_date + " " + current_time
with open(f'shopee_{current_date}.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Product Name', 'Parent SKU', 'Price', 'Seller Stock', 'Shopee Stock', 'Sales'])
# data = [
#     ["Product_Name", "Parent_SKU","Price", "Seller_Stock", "Shopee_Stock","Sales"],
#     # Add more rows of data here if needed
# ]
# with open(f'shopee_{current_date}.csv', 'w')as file:
#     writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
#     writer.writerows(data)

driver.get('https://url')
time.sleep(3)

englishh = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class, "language-selection__list-item")]/button[contains(@class, "shopee-button-outline") and contains(@class, "shopee-button-outline--primary-reverse") and text()="English"]')
englishh.click()
time.sleep(5)
loginnn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="PfeIJo"][text()="Login with Main/Sub Account"]')
loginnn.click()
time.sleep(5)

# Find and fill in the email input field
email_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="text"]')
email_input.send_keys('username')
# Find and fill in the password input field
password_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="password"]')
password_input.send_keys('password')
# Click on the "Next" button
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="shopee-button login-btn shopee-button--primary shopee-button--large shopee-button--block"]')
login_button.click()
time.sleep(30)

#gggg = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/i')
#gggg.click()
#time.sleep(20)

pppppp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/button')
pppppp.click()
time.sleep(3)

myproduct = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[@href="/portal/product/list/all" and @class="sidebar-submenu-item-link"]/span[text()="My Products"]')
myproduct.click()
time.sleep(10)

while True:
    productname=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="product-name-text"]')
    parentsku=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product-sku"]')
    sellerstock=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="stock-text"]/span')
    campaginprice = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="price-campaign-box allow-edit"]')
    shopeestock=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product-list-item__td product-variation__shopee-stock"]/div/div/div/div/span')
    shopeesales = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product-list-item__td product-variation__sales"]/div')

    with open(f'shopee_{current_date}.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)

        # Iterate over the data and write each item to a separate row
        for g in range(len(productname)):
            # Check if the index is within the range of all lists
            if (
                    g < len(parentsku) or
                    g < len(campaginprice) or
                    g < len(sellerstock) or
                    g < len(shopeestock) or
                    g < len(shopeesales)
            ):
                data_row = [
                    productname[g].text,
                    parentsku[g].text if g < len(parentsku) and parentsku[g].text not in ['', '-'] else 'N/A',
                    campaginprice[g].text if g < len(campaginprice) and campaginprice[g].text not in ['', '-'] else 'N/A',
                    sellerstock[g].text if g < len(sellerstock) and sellerstock[g].text not in ['', '-'] else 'N/A',
                    shopeestock[g].text if g < len(shopeestock) and shopeestock[g].text not in ['', '-'] else 'N/A',
                    shopeesales[g].text if g < len(shopeesales) and shopeesales[g].text not in ['', '-'] else 'N/A'
                ]

                writer.writerow(data_row)
            else:
                # Handle the case where one of the lists doesn't have enough elements
                data_row = [
                    productname[g].text,
                    'N/A' if g >= len(parentsku) or parentsku[g].text in ['', '-'] else parentsku[g].text,
                    'N/A' if g >= len(campaginprice) or campaginprice[g].text in ['', '-'] else campaginprice[g].text,
                    'N/A' if g >= len(sellerstock) or sellerstock[g].text in ['', '-'] else sellerstock[g].text,
                    'N/A' if g >= len(shopeestock) or shopeestock[g].text in ['', '-'] else shopeestock[g].text,
                    'N/A' if g >= len(shopeesales) or shopeesales[g].text in ['', '-'] else shopeesales[g].text
                ]

                writer.writerow(data_row)

    next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button[2]')
    if not next_button.is_enabled():
        break  # Exit the loop if there is no next page

        # Click the next page button
    next_button.click()
    time.sleep(3)

finally:
# Quit the browser
#time.sleep(120)
driver.quit()'
```

*end code*
Help me create a code that the web scraped data will automatically upload in Sharepoint.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).